# When does the characteristic length deem a layer infinitely thin?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, definition

When reading [Real-time terahertz imaging with a single-pixel detector](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-16370-x) a paragraph states:

*"(...) these carriers will diffuse inside the semiconductor with a characteristic length around ~ 0.3 mm rendering the infinitely thin conductive layer approximation invalid."*

**I thought 0.3 mm would be a very thin layer, but apparently it still isn't thin enough to consider it to be infinitely thin. So from what value is it viable to make such an assumption?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, 0.3 mm is sort of thin, but such approximations tend to be valid only when some number is small relative to another. I think the relevant comparison here is between this characteristic length and the wavelength of the THz radiation used. While I didn't see what frequency they used at a quick glance, it's worth noting that 1 THz corresponds to $\lambda=0.3$ mm.

You may want to look to [this review article](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.83.543) for a broader perspective.